# How Can I use two "use" keyword on same page php

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using two libraries on the same page. One is for pdf generation and one is for sending emails. But, this giving me error 500 - llease advise .

After some debugging, I found that it's phpmailer mails not working because of dompdf:

```
require_once 'lib/dompdf/vendor/autoload.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 

require 'lib/phpmailer/vendor/autoload.php'; 


use Dompdf\Dompdf;
class Pdf extends Dompdf{
public function __construct(){
 parent::__construct();
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check the PHP Fatal error message, so you can yourself trouble shoot the issue.

Comment: no fatal error its  $mail->isSMTP();  causing problem

Comment: Check logs. What is the error?  How about requiring all files and then `use`ing them?

Comment: @vivek_23 dompdf library not letting emails sent

Comment: Any good reason to use both phpmailer and dompdf inside the same execution context? Also, is this inside a framework, say codeigniter?

Comment: I am confused of seeing two autoloaders.

Comment: @vivek_23 no corephp

Comment: @MarkusZeller I am trying to generate pdf and sent that pdf via email on same page

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in your code is the duplicate autoloader. The best way is when you install both packages over composer and use the composer autoloader.

In both libs you can find an example how to install them over composer.

```
composer require dompdf/dompdf
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

Then you have to include the autoloader for composer.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

After that you can use the autoloader to load all packages. In the DomPDF you find good examples how to use.

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

500 errors are a bit hard to find. You should enable your error logs and check directly your logs. In the log a php error should be shown.

Answer (score 1):

By using alias:

```
use \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\{PHPMailer as mailerClass, Exception as mailerException}; // PHP 7+
```